# Reference error variable not define on Object forEach

Tags: javascript

[image: see when console.log(x) commented.. w.push overwrite previous value][image: console.log(x) not commented.. w.push not overwrite previous value and add current value accordind to filtervalue like color, size,fit, brand]I am getting reference error w is not defined in forEach object.
this.primaryfilterdata is product json object.

```
this.primaryfilterdata =[{"id":"Brand","filterValues":[{"id":" FIDO DIDO","count":1,"meta":""},{"id":"addidas","count":1,"meta":""},{"id":"hrx","count":3,"meta":""},{"id":"nike","count":1,"meta":""},{"id":"polo","count":2,"meta":""}]},{"id":"fit","filterValues":[{"id":"28","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"30","count":5,"meta":null},{"id":"32","count":4,"meta":null},{"id":"34","count":3,"meta":null}],"checked":[]},{"id":"color","filterValues":[{"id":"black","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"orange","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"red","count":5,"meta":null},{"id":"yellow","count":6,"meta":null}],"checked":[]},{"id":"size","filterValues":[{"id":"l","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"m","count":5,"meta":null},{"id":"s","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"x","count":3,"meta":null},{"id":"xl","count":2,"meta":null}],"checked":[]}]
Here is code

    var pfquery={}
    Object.keys(this.primaryfilterdata).forEach(function(key,index){
      var x=this.primaryfilterdata[key].filterValues
      var atrval=this.primaryfilterdata[key].id
      var w=[];     
      Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key1,value){
        //console.log("Original array:", key1);
        var y=x[key1]
        if(y.checked) {
          w.push(y.id);
          pfquery[atrval]=[];
          pfquery[atrval].push(w);
        }       
      })

    }.bind(this));

    console.log(pfquery)
    console.log(w)
```

Comment: w is local scoped within the function ,so console.log(w) means nothing

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON data i.e.: `primaryfilterdata`

Comment: @TomO. i post the json data

Comment: @Shubh if i remove that console.log(x) .. w.push overwrite the previous value..kindly suggest

Comment: I really don't know what you are trying to achieve here  coz console.log(w) will throw exception because w is not in the global scope it is defined inside function's local scope ,rest your code looks syntactically correct .I am not sure about the concept  you are applying though.

Comment: @Shubh  actually major problem is w.push is overwrite previous value ..but i think my code is right why it overwrite previous value..but when i write console.log(w) .. it not write previous value and push current value which is correct  but throw this error w is not define

Comment: Can you explain what your actual end-goal is here instead of asking about the solution that isn't working? See: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You're reassigning an empty array to `w` variable inside a loop. That's why `w` is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, i believe you are trying to get an object(pfquery) as a result which hold the id of the brands which is checked/selected.

Output like this :

```
{"Brand":["FIDO DIDO", "nike"]}
```

first the console.log(w) is mentioned in the wrong place, out of scope. So remove that line, that's the reason you are getting this error.

And i believe the "checked" field in your json object is not mentioned in the right place, i think it should be mentioned inside all the brands filtervalues. then only your code check (if(y.checked)) will work/execute.

Below is the Sample JSON which you have to specify to make your code work properly.

```
this.primaryfilterdata =[{"id":"Brand","filterValues":[{"id":" FIDO DIDO","count":1,"meta":"", "checked": true},{"id":"addidas","count":1,"meta":"", "checked": true} ]}]
```

I hope this is what you are expecting to do.

Comment: actually there are checkbox  of filter values on check these checked property get true

Comment: Then I guess your mentioned JSON object is not correct. Can you check on this based on my comments.